# feature dimension after LDA dimension reduction is unexpected

Tags: scikit-learn

Hi I have 5994 classes and my original feature dimension is 300, and I have 1092008 samples, when I put n_components=200 it gives me dimension of 33? Do you have some idea?

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
lda_model = LDA(n_components=lda_dim)
lda_model.fit(x_train,labels)
x_train = lda_model.transform(x_train)
```

So the original dimension of the x_train is (1092008, 300) then after the dimension reduction I expected to receive an array of dimension (1092008, 200) but I receive (1092008, 33).

Is there something wrong with the use of LDA or what?